# uploading image and text in same mysql table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload image and text in a same mysql table in codeigniter but i'm getting a database error like "You must use the "set" method to update an entry."

code on controller

```
class Addnews extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('addnews', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1040';
    $config['max_height']  = '1040';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $newRow = array("news_title" => $this->input->post('news_title'),
                    "news_description" => $this->input->post('news_description'));
            $data = array('upload' => $this->upload->data());

        $result = array_merge($newRow, $data);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
         $image_data = $this->upload->data();
       $newRow['imgpath'] ='assets/images/'.$image_data['file_name'];
        $this->load->view('addnews');
    }
    else
    {

    $this->load->model("modeladdnews");
    $this->modeladdnews->insert_news($result);   

 $this->load->view('success');
    }
}
}
?>
```

code on model

```
<?php
class Modeladdnews extends CI_Model {
  function insert_news($result)
  {
     $this->db->insert('news');

  }
  }
  ?>
```

code on view

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>


 <?php echo form_open_multipart('Addnews/do_upload');?>
 <?php
  echo form_input("news_title", "");
  echo form_input("news_description", "");
  echo form_upload("userfile");
  ?>
  <br /><br />

 <input type="submit" value="submit" />

 </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CI active record class insert method accepts two arguments 1st is table_name and second is array you are not sending the data in insert function see it should be like this.

```
class Modeladdnews extends CI_Model {
      function insert_news($result)
      {
         $this->db->insert('news',$result);


      }
 }
```

Comment: it shows A PHP error " Array to string conversion" and a A Database Error "Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'" ...... I'm very new to codeigniter, would you like to explain the error ? thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

your concept is wrong: uploading a file is one thing, updating database is another! Once the image is uploaded (to a directory on your server), you'll want to save the image path and other image data (like date, description, etc.) in your database or execute some image manipulation.

You should have your do_upload controller organized like this:

```
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        //error
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        // success!!, file was uploaded
        // get data for this file;          
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $img = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $data['other_stuff']=$_POST;
        // Now update the database
        $this->modeladdnews->insert_news($data);
    }
```

Comment: it shows A PHP error " Array to string conversion" and a A Database Error "Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'" ...... I'm very new to codeigniter, would you like to explain the error ? thanks in advance....

Comment: just to put you into the right direction: you can use 'print_r($result)' to see the array output. You may not have an array within an array in order to work with '$this->db->insert('news',$result);' The array entries must match your database table columns

Answer (score 0):

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/images';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|JPG|PNG|GIF';
    $config['max_size'] = '20000';
    $config['max_width'] = '102400';
    $config['max_height'] = '76800';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) { 
        echo "Error While uploading image ! please go back and try again";
    } else {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $data['image'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
        $data['caption'] = $_POST['caption'];
        $this->db->insert('tbl_name', $data); }
```